# Excel 2007 workbook where each sheet is a duplicate of the previous where I'm only concerned with

Tags: excel-formula

I have an Excel 2007 workbook where each sheet is a duplicate of the previous where I'm only concerned with one row where every other cell's last value increments by 7. I'm already referencing an earlier sheet to to correlate the value of the cell but now I need to increment the last value by 7 (i.e. week)

For Example: 
Sheet 103 row 3 has the following values:

- cell A3 has a value of =Sheet79!A3+168
- cell C3 has a value of =Sheet79!C3+168
- cell E3 has a value of =Sheet79!E3+168
- cell G3 has a value of =Sheet79!G3+168
- cell I3 has a value of =Sheet79!I3+168
- cell K3 has a value of =Sheet79!K3+168
- cell M3 has a value of =Sheet79!M3+168

Sheet 104 row 3 has the following values:

- cell A3 has a value of =Sheet79!A3+175
- cell C3 has a value of =Sheet79!C3+175
- cell E3 has a value of =Sheet79!E3+175
- cell G3 has a value of =Sheet79!G3+175
- cell I3 has a value of =Sheet79!I3+175
- cell K3 has a value of =Sheet79!K3+175
- cell M3 has a value of =Sheet79!M3+175

Sheet 105 row 3 has the following values:

- cell A3 has a value of =Sheet79!A3+182
- cell C3 has a value of =Sheet79!C3+182
- cell E3 has a value of =Sheet79!E3+182
- cell G3 has a value of =Sheet79!G3+182
- cell I3 has a value of =Sheet79!I3+182
- cell K3 has a value of =Sheet79!K3+182
- cell M3 has a value of =Sheet79!M3+182

How can I automate the replication of this sequence for row 3 in an unlimited number of sheets?  Seems simple enough, but I don't know how to compensate for every other column.  Currently I'm editing the last value manually, but that's a slow & tedious process.  Thanks in advance for your help. :-)

Comment: Please reformat your post (maybe list or table style) - it's hard to read.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Andreas.  I reformatted the cell references as a list.

Comment: Your design is flawed. You should put the value (e.g., `168` in a single cell on the sheet, and have the other cells reference it instead of individually adding `+168` to each formula. With it in a single cell, your task is easy. Read the value of that cell on your current last page, add 7 to it, and put that new value into the same cell on your new page. Your formulas can then simply be copied into the new sheet.

Comment: Thanks Ken, however I have tried to do what you suggested and it's not working.  Could you provide a sample of what would go in that new cell?  I tried inputting =182+7 for that new cell but that doesn't work. I then tried =0+7 and that didn't work either.  I then tried inputting this formula in the last cell in row 3 and Excel says it's not a valid formula =Sheet79!M3!Sheet106!O3  So obviously I don't know what I'm doing.  It may be simple to you... but not me.

Comment: In cell A3 in the next sheet I input =Sheet79!A3+Sheet106!O3 but this displays Sunday September 30, 2018 rather than Sunday April 7, 2019.

Comment: Here's where I stand now, I'm up to sheet 108 and the value I have in cell M3 is =Sheet79!M3+203 and the date displayed in that cell is Saturday April 20, 2019.  Therefore in Sheet 109 cell A3 I need to display the date of Sunday April 21, 2019. Specifically how do I make that happen?